# Flutter Gradle Issues

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-dependencies

Hiya i'm constantly getting this issue, i tried all the possible solution, but is still not working. Can someone please help me out.

[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time: 100ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':device_info_plus'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':device_info_plus:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :device_info_plus
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':device_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':device_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #2, wait time: 200ms

it's not running, constaly shows gradle issues

Comment: Did you try to Uninstall gradle file and re install that file?

Comment: No i. tried but it didn't work, is there any other way to resolve it